# How to call component method from Resolver in Angular2+?

Tags: angular

My components (many) need to load data from the backend before they are rendered. Implementing a Resolver seems to be what Angular suggests. (I read about Guards and *resolve()* here:
https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#milestone-5-route-guards )

Now I *could* write one Resolver for each of my components. But I'm looking for a way to store the information, *What data do I need?*, within the components, then have one Service take care of loading the data.

Something like:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DataResolverGuard implements Resolve<any>
{
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        const dataPackagesToLoad: IDataPackage[] = componentThatsAboutToLoad.whatDataDoYouNeed();
        return this.dataService.loadPackages(dataPackagesToLoad);
    }
}
```

But: How do I get `componentThatsAboutToLoad` into the *resolve()* method?

OR: What *other* ways are there that work on `Observable` and interrupt/block/delay the components' `ngOnInit()` until all neccessary data has been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Guards are used to deciding whether to show or block visiting a route depending upon conditions. Router Resolvers are used to perform an operation before routing . We can perform operations in Guards as well . But according to your requirment using a route resolver would be ideal. Pfb a sample resolver usage :

**test.resolver.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {SharedService} from './shared.service';
 
@Injectable()
export class DataResolverGuard implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private sharedService:SharedService) {}
  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> | any{
        const url = 'http://testsite.com/fetchData';
        return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
import {DataResolverGuard} from './test.resolver';
import {TestComponent} from './test.compoenent';
import {NewComponent} from './new.compoenent';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: TestComponent,
},{
    path: 'newRoute', component: NewComponent,resolve: { resolvedData: DataResolverGuard}
}]
```

**new.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {SharedService} from './shared.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'new-comp',
    templateUrl: './new.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./new.component.scss']
})

export class NewComponent {
dataFromResolver:any;
 constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute,private shared:SharedService ){
    this.dataFromResolver = this.route.snapshot.data['resolvedData'];
    this.shared.setMyResolvedData(this.dataFromResolver);
    console.log(this.dataFromResolver)
 }
}
```

**shared.service.ts**

```
 import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class SharedService {
    
    setMyResolvedData(incomingData){
    console.log(incomingData)
    }

}
```

Hope i have answered your whole requirement :-)

Comment: Hey Arun, thanks for your help. I try something a bit different. I have ~60 components that need to load *different* data each (but all of the same type). So the Resolver needs to ask: "Component, what data should I load for you?" Of course, strictly speaking the component doesn't even exist yet, because the router hasn't completed navigation. Might need to implement separate Resolvers for each route. Hoped to avoid that by "somehow injecting" the component-to-be. OR by loading my data in ngOnInit() of each component, but that would need to be *synchronous*. No idea if that's even possible...

Comment: @Robin did you find a way to what you describe? I want to do the exact thing.

Comment: @AurelijusRozenas I ended up having separate Resolvers for each route.